# Python skipping lines when printing

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

So, I i'm creating a script that will try out some emails and tell me if they're valid or not but the problem is, it's skipping lines when printing them out too be BUT it types the perfectly fine. I'll show you.
I'll try these 5 emails.

```
gabriel_su
bloodown
xdiablo89
sc.orion
peanut
```

It prints back this..

```
bloodown
Is taken
sc.orion
 Is available
SHAMS
Is taken
kjadair12
Is taken
super_robin75
Is taken
```

which some are not even in my 5 lines "super_robin75" is my 10th line..

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

txt = open("emails.txt", 'r')

chrome_path = r"C:\Users\Skid\Desktop\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_path)
for x in range(5):
    driver.get("https://signup.live.com/signup?wa=wsignin1.0&rpsnv=12&ct=1455592987&rver=6.4.6456.0&wp=MBI_SSL_SHARED&wreply=https%3a%2f%2fmail.live.com%2fdefault.aspx%3frru%3dinbox&id=64855&cbcxt=mai&bk=1455592987&uiflavor=web&uaid=947b22b7c0d249f8ab527df4fb06c828&mkt=EN-US&lc=1033&lic=1")


    driver.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id="memberNameDomain"]""").click()
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id="CredentialsInputPane"]/fieldset/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/ul/li[2]/a""").click()


    type_into_email = driver.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id="MemberName"]""")
    type_into_email.send_keys(txt.readline())


    refresh = driver.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id="FirstName"]""").click()
    time.sleep(5)

    error = driver.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id="MemberNameError"]""")
    if error.is_displayed():
        print(txt.readline() + "Is taken")
    else:
        print(txt.readline() + " Is available")
```

Comment: You are calling `txt.readline()` multiple times per iteration; is that intentions? You probably want something like `for name in txt:`, then use `name` where ever you are currently calling `txt.readline()`.

Comment: Post an answer with an solution please

Comment: I have no idea where I would put that

Comment: That's the loop to use instead of `for x in range(5)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to use

```
for line in txt.readlines()
```

loop instead of

```
for x in range(5)
```

and

```
if error.is_displayed():
    print(line + "Is taken")
else:
    print(line + " Is available")
```

Comment: The call to `readlines()` is unnecessary and inefficient. Just use `for line in txt`

Comment: Thank you, Worked perfectly

Answer (score 0):

You specify `x in range(5)` so it is a normal behaviour that the ouput is 5-lines long.

You should loop like follow:

```
for x in txt:
   ...
   type_into_email.send_keys(x)
   ...
   if error.is_displayed():
       print(x.strip() + "Is taken")
   else:
       print(x.strip() + " Is available")
```

Comment: Alright I tried it that, it only spits out on character when typing but it might be good if we can fix that..

Comment: as @chepner mentionned, you can only type `for x in txt:`

Answer (score 0):

To be clear, you want thr results on the same line, correct? To do that, change your print lines to `print (txt.readline().strip() + ...` to remove the newline character

Comment: That took away the spacing stuff, that's good thank you but, I'm stilling having my 1st problem where it's printing it every other lineex